# Redirect happens, still the old page is showing

Tags: angularjs

In my controller, I have a redirection like this, from the signin page to the index page.

```
var loginApp = angular.module('angularRestfulAuth', ['ngCookies', 'ngStorage',
    'ngRoute',
    'angular-loading-bar']);
loginApp
    .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location','$cookies','$window',  'Main', function($rootScope, $scope, $location,$cookies, $window,Main) {

        $scope.signin = function() {
            var formData = {
                username: $scope.username,
                password: $scope.password
            }

            Main.signin(formData, function(res) {
                if (res.type == false) {
                    alert(res.data) ;  
                } else {
                  //location.href='/index'; 
                  $window.location.assign('/index');
                }
            }, function() {
                $rootScope.error = 'Failed to signin';
            })
        };
```

app.js looks like,

```
angular.module('angularRestfulAuth', [
    'ngStorage',
    'ngRoute',
    'angular-loading-bar'
])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider','$cookies','$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider,$cookies,$locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider.     
        when('/index', {
           templateUrl: 'app/partials/index.html',
                controller: 'myController'

        }).
        when('/signin', {
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/signin.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
         $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

If I use, `location.href='/index';`

then,

`http://localhost:5000/index`

Error:Cannot GET /index

If I use,  `$location.url('/index');`

then ,

`http://localhost:5000/#/index`

But still showing the signin page, instead of index page.

Comment: Try use `$location.path()`

Comment: i wonder your both template URLs are different, even they are at same place

Comment: @Hadi: Tried that.. then `http://localhost:5000/#/index` but still showing the current signin page.

Comment: @the_mishra: template url, I just changed to test it. But now I am referring to `when('/index' ` only

Comment: Is your template URl correct coz I can see two different sets for '/index' and '/signin' ...one has app

Comment: @Vivz: Updated the qestion. I just changed to test it. But now I am referring to when('/index' only

Comment: Do yo have a particular reason for not using states ? RouteProvider is not recommanded in comparison to StateProvider now

Comment: @Alburkerk: No I will try that.

Comment: @Alburkerk: Same issue. Url seems http://localhost:5000/#/index but still showing signin page itself

Comment: Have you done $state.go instead of $location.assign ?